# Tf roslaunch issue, Package Path not set up properly?

Tags: turtlebot, catkin, path, package, ros-groovy

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I've been trying to launch the learning_tf package from the tf tutorials, and seem unable to find it, no matter how much I change my env variables.  The command is "roslaunch learning_tf start_demo.launch" but it's also failing on other commands.

The workspace I'm using is ~/catkin_ws/src
I'm operating on groovy.

I'm convinced that the problem has to do with what I should set my ROS_PACKAGE_PATH to, but I don't know what it should be.  I've tried several different options, and can normally locate things in /opt/ros/groovy/stacks, but not packages in catkin_ws.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/61877/tf-roslaunch-issue,-package-path-not-set-up-properly?/) by [mlpayne1](https://answers.ros.org/users/4796/mlpayne1/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2013-04-30

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You should not set your ROS_PACKAGE_PATH. Source the setup.bash/setup.sh within the catkin workspace, usually at devel/setup.bash.

---

Originally posted by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) with karma: 31395 on 2013-04-30

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [mlpayne1](https://answers.ros.org/users/4796/mlpayne1/) on 2013-05-01**:
Thank You, this appears to have solved the issue